# Setting qgis-server environment variables

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, environment-variable

I need to know how to set qgis-server environment variables, because I can't find a good explanation of how this works here on the SE or in the documentation. The specific environment variable I am trying to set is `QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING`.

I have searched within many directories that contain the miscellaneous workings of qgis-server and Apache 2, but it doesn't seem to be located within any .cfg/.ini files I have found.

I don't think it matters much, but I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 21.04, qgis and qgis-server 3.2, and Lizmap 3.4.4.

pic 1 *shows the variables, but not how to set them*
[image: qgis server documentation page]

pic 2 *explains what happens without explaining what happens*
[image: confusion #2]

Answer (score 2):

Considering, you deployed QGIS Server with Apache FCGI (If other approaches, recipe/answer would change)

You can set the environment variable within Apache configuration file with

```
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING "1"
```

You can inspect [this sample code for an example in context](https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-server-docker/blob/production/default.conf#L28)

**Two ways to find out the answer**:

*Simple one*:

- Go to https://github.com and do a search using keyword `QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING` like this url https://github.com/search?q=QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING
- Then, on the left, click on "Code" to get an url like https://github.com/search?p=2&q=QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING&type=Code
- Then, inspect results to try to find relevant samples

*Complex one*:

If already familiar with Apache, looking at https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/plugins.html#http-server-configuration that mentioned below

> FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PLUGINPATH "/var/www/qgis-server/plugins"

and see that `QGIS_PLUGINPATH` was mentioned in https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/config.html#environment-variables to guess how to use `QGIS_SERVER_PARALLEL_RENDERING`. Must admit this way is not easy.